# Verify $U + W = \{(x,x,y,z) \in F^4 : x,y,z \in F\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $U = \{(x,x,y,y)\in F^4:x,y \in \mathbb F\}$ and $W = \{(x,x,x,y) \in \mathbb F^4: x,y \in \mathbb F\}$. Then verify that
$$U + W = \{(x,x,y,z) \in \mathbb F^4: x,y,z \in \mathbb F\}$$

I found the solution [here](http://linearalgebras.com/1c.html), but I can only follow the first few lines.

I can follow till the following lines
\begin{align*} &(x_1,x_1,y_1,y_1)+(x_2,x_2,x_2,y_2)\\=&(x_1+x_2,x_1+x_2,y_1+x_2,y_1+y_2) \in \{(x,x,y,z):x,y,z\in\mathbb F^4\}. \end{align*}

But what happens here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

He want to prove that the two sets $U+W$ and $\{(x,x,y,z)\}$ are  equal.

The first step  is to prove $U+W\subset\{(x,x,y,z)\}$ and the second is to prove $\{(x,x,y,z)\}\subset U+W$.

To prove the second one, he construct each element of $\{(x,x,y,z)\}$ by using two corresponding elements in $U$ and $V$ respectively.